# jquery ui tooltip manual open /close

Tags: jquery-ui, tooltip

is there a way to manually open close the jquery ui tooltip?  I just want it to react to a click event toggling on/off.  You can unbind all mouse events and it will rebind them when calling .tooltip('open'), even though that should not initialize or set events imo, since if you try to run .tooltip('open') without initializing, it complains loudly about not being initialized.

Comment: I need to manually open it, but with the mouse tracking enabled.  The mouse track doesn't seem to work if you manually open it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

jltwoo, can I suggest to use two different boolean switches to enable auto-open and auto-close? With this change your code will look like this:

```
(function( $ ) {
  $.widget( "custom.tooltipX", $.ui.tooltip, {
    options: {
        autoShow: true,
        autoHide: true
    },

    _create: function() {
      this._super();
      if(!this.options.autoShow){
        this._off(this.element, "mouseover focusin");
      }
    },

    _open: function( event, target, content ) {
      this._superApply(arguments);

      if(!this.options.autoHide){
        this._off(target, "mouseleave focusout");
      }
    }
  });

}( jQuery ) );
```

In this way, initializing the tooltip as:

```
$(someDOM).tooltipX({ autoHide:false });
```

it shows by itself when the mouse is over the element but you have to manually close it.

If you want to manually control both open and close actions, you can simply use:

```
$(someDOM).tooltipX({ autoShow:false, autoHide:false });
```

Comment: Working fiddle on this answer - I've also simplified the click bind to a one-liner ! :) (assignment expression returns assigned value) ::: https://jsfiddle.net/nuv8v1ct/

Answer (score 11):

If you want to just unbind the events and woudn't like to make your own custom tooltip.

```
$("#some-id").tooltip(tooltip_settings)
             .on('mouseout focusout', function(event) {
                  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
             });

$("#some-id").attr("title", "Message");
$("#some-id").tooltip("open");
```

**mouseout** blocks the tooltop disappearing by moving the mouse cursor

**focusout** blocks the tooltop disappearing by keyboard navigation

Answer (score 7):

The tooltip have a disable option. Well i used it and here is the code:

```
$('a').tooltip({
    disabled: true    
}).click(function(){    
    if($(this).tooltip('option', 'disabled'))
        $(this).tooltip('option', {disabled: false}).tooltip('open');
    else
        $(this).tooltip('option', {disabled: true}).tooltip('close');
}).hover(function(){
    $(this).tooltip('option', {disabled: true}).tooltip('close');
}, function(){
    $(this).tooltip('option', {disabled: true}).tooltip('close');
});
```

Comment: I tried that. While it works in your example, in reality (after reading the code) there's no real way of blocking the automatic closing of the tooltip upon mouseleave.

Comment: this works: close: function( event, ui ) { ui.tooltip.stop(); [link](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-animation)

Comment: @Antonimo The code you've shown only stops the animation, if you actually check the domTree it's creating multiple ui-tooltip DOMs, definitely not something preferred. Unfortunately the way the jquery-ui tooltip is coded, the mouselease/focusout events are attached after the "open" event so we cannot easily remove those events after they are attached to prevent the tooltip from closing. Same goes with close event being called only after state variables are cleared, it would be too late to stop. Until the tooltip is further improved, we'll just have to extend it and make our own customizations.

Answer (score 5):

Related to my other comment, I looked into the original code and achieved manual open/close by extending the widget and adding a autoHide option with version JQuery-UI v1.10.3. Basically I just remove the mouse listeners that were added in _create and the internal _open call.

**Edit:** Separated autoHide and autoShow as two separate flags as suggested by @MscG

**Demo Here:**
http://jsfiddle.net/BfSz3/

```
(function( $ ) {
  $.widget( "custom.tooltipX", $.ui.tooltip, {
    options: {
      autoHide:true,
      autoShow: true
    },

    _create: function() {
      this._super();
      if(!this.options.autoShow){
        this._off(this.element, "mouseover focusin");
      }
    },

    _open: function( event, target, content ) {
      this._superApply(arguments);

      if(!this.options.autoHide){
        this._off(target, "mouseleave focusout");
      }
    }
  });

}( jQuery ) );
```

Now when you initialize you can set the tooltip to manually show or hide by setting autoHide : false:

```
 $(someDOM).tooltipX({ autoHide:false });
```

And just directly perform standard open/close calls in your code as needed elsewhere

```
 $(someDOM).tooltipX("open"); // displays tooltip
 $(someDOM).tooltipX("close"); // closes tooltip
```

A simple hotfix, until I have the time to do official pull request, this will have to do.

Answer (score 0):

Some compilation from other SO questions.

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/9mff4scL/4/)
Show tooltip on `hint` click, and hide tooltip on elsevere click

```
$(document).on('click', '.hint', function(){ //init new tooltip on click
   $(this).tooltip({
      position: { my: 'left+15 center', at: 'center right' },
      show: false,
      hide: false
   }).tooltip('open'); // show new tooltip
}).on('click', function(event){ // click everywhere
   if(!$(event.target).hasClass('hint'))
     $(".hint").each(function(){
        var $element = $(this);
        if($element.data('ui-tooltip')) { // remove tooltip only from initialized elements
           $element.tooltip('destroy');
        }
     })
});

$('.hint').on('mouseout focusout', function(event) { // prevent auto hide tooltip 
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```