# Positioning tool tip using .css()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I created a tooltip with CSS and I want to position the arrow just above the icon of each button. I tried using jQuery Mobile but it has not worked for me so the easiest way for me to accomplish this now is to position the tool tip manually :(

Also I was wondering if manually positioning the tooltip would change in anyway if I were to use this page on a mobile app with a different resolution or perhaps shrink the page size?

What I've tried it to use `.offset()` to get my tool tip class around the relative area of each button id.

```
var CS_x_pos = $("#CS").offset();
var CS_y_pos = $("#CS").offset();

var GH_x_pos = $("#GH").offset();
var GH_y_pos = $("#GH").offset();

//CS
$(".tooltip").css({
    left: CS_x_pos, 
    top: CS_y_pos 
});


//GH
$(".tooltip").css({
    left: GH_x_pos, 
    top: GH_y_pos 
});
```

When I try:

```
var CS_x_pos = $("#CS").offset().left;
var CS_y_pos = $("#CS").offset().top;
```

I get this:

[image]

I am not sure why the tool tip ends up on the bottom

[image]

Here is my jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/liondancer/rKPfe/

I thought `.offset()` would position the tooltips around the relative area but it is still pretty far =/

Could someone help me or guide me to manually positioning these tool tips? Much appreciated!

Comment: Please include the code in your post as well.

Comment: Have you looked at http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/?

Comment: @SpYk3HH I did but I was suggested that I do not add an entire library for this small feature =/

Comment: You don't have to get the entire library, and it wouldn't hurt anyway. Since you're designing "mobile", then you can expect the users to have an OS and browser that will handle the small footprint and couple extra "mili"seconds with no problem. But You can download any "piece" of jQuery UI. Just go to [downloads](http://jqueryui.com/download/) section and look at the checkboxes. Click `Toggle all` to undo all of them. then scroll down to `widgets` section and check `tooltip`, thus making your download ONLY whats needed for that widget

Comment: U will still use the jqueryui style classes to style however you please (exp.  `.ui-tooltip { background: #000; }`

Comment: Plus one to SpYk3HH's suggestion despite the flagrant misuse of quotes. :-D

Comment: LoL @isherwood. +1 to isherwood answer somewhere at random for making me lol!

Comment: @SpYk3HH the functionality of this notification is similar to JQM's `.popup()`. However, external forces causes improper positioning of the popup to the element so I decided to use manually positioning. How this feature works is that some data turns on and off in my database causing the notification to notify the users ON or OFF. Will JQ-UI tooltip do the samething? I took a quick glance and it seems to focus more on hovering over an element and displaying text.

Comment: Yes [stackoverflow.com...jquery-ui-tooltip-manual-open-close](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13057606/jquery-ui-tooltip-manual-open-close) Maybe also see http://bit.ly/1c0rY3T

Comment: @SpYk3HH Ill give it a shot and let you know what happens! thanks for the help!

Comment: @SpYk3HH I tried `($.tooltip).position({at:"#CS"});` and `($.tooltip).position({of:"#CS"})` However no luck =/ they stay in the same place. I was hoping this function put the tooltip class and put it where teh CS button is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of plugin related to tooltip. like [tipsy](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/) or jQuery ui and many more you can find on googling.

If you want it to do completely with css, the best approach is to wrap tooltip and trigger element. like

```
<div class="holder"> 
<div class = "tooltip">
        <div class = "tooltip_body"> GH is OFF
            <div class = "tooltip_arrow"></div>
        </div>
 </div>
 <a class="holder" data-role="button" data-icon="plus"> GH</a>
 </div>
```

Than you can give css of tooltip relative to your trigger element.
like `bottom: 60px; right:0;`

Note : Give `display:inline-block` and `position:relative;` on holder so it not require any extra space and tooltip will absolute to holder

Check [fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rKPfe/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/rKPfe/3/)

**Update**

If you are not sure about the bottom position you can do with jQuery;

```
$('.tooltip').each(function(){
   var elm=$(this),
       holder=elm.closest('.holder');
   elm.css('bottom',holder.outerHeight()+'px');
});
```

Left and right you can give relative(like left:0 or right:0) to holder position( which is not affected by changing window size) . Only in case if you want tooltip to be centered respect to holder yo can write.

```
$('.tooltip').each(function(){
   var elm=$(this),
       holder=elm.closest('.holder');
   elm.css({
    'bottom':holder.height()+'px',
    'left':-(elm.outerWidth()-holder.outerWidth())/2+'px'
   });
});
```

Comment: Do you know if manually positioning like this will change the positioning of these tool tips on different resolutions or perhaps a tablet?

Comment: @Liondancer You can do with jquery to find the bottom position. Check update.

Comment: what about something such as the right and left position changing? Im a new to CSS and overall front-end design.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are not taking into account the height and width of the tooltip itself.

Calculate its height and width and minus this off of the top and left values.

```
var width = parseFloat($(".tooltip").css('width'));
var height = parseFloat($(".tooltip").css('height'));

$(".tooltip").css({
    left: CS_x_pos - width, 
    top: CS_y_pos - height 
});
```

Comment: Do you know if manually positioning like this will change the positioning of these tool tips on different resolutions or perhaps a tablet?

Comment: I edited my jsfiddle and included your width and height variables and added it to my `.css()` but nothing happened =/

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't have any Javascript... I can't fiddle with it!

Comment: do you like type R's?