# tooltip positionining and hiding tooltip immedately after mouse is moved out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using jquery API to show tooltip. I want to position the tooltip immediate near the image on mouseover on the image in the table and when i mouse over the images quickly previous tooltip is
still seen ,can i fadeout the tooltip immediately once the mouse is moved away from the image. Please find the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/0w9yo8x6/4/
Below is the code snippet:

```
$(function () {
    $(document).tooltip({
        content: function () {
            return $(this).prop('title');
        },
        show: null, 
        close: function (event, ui) {
            ui.tooltip.hover(

            function () {
                $(this).stop(true).fadeTo(400, 1);
            },

            function () {
                $(this).fadeOut("400", function () {
                    $(this).remove();
                })
            });
        }
    });
});

$(function () {
  $('.one').attr('title', $('.tooltipTable').remove().html());
  $(document).tooltip();
});
$(function () {
      $('.one').attr('title', $('.tooltipTable').remove().html());
      $(document).tooltip();
    });
```

Comment: Maybe see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13057606/jquery-ui-tooltip-manual-open-close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of implementing your own "close" function you simply can set the `show` and `hide` properties to `false` when creating the tooltip.

have a look at the documentation [show](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-show) / [hide](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-hide)

```
$(document).tooltip({
    content: function () {
        return $(this).prop('title');
    },
    show: false,
    hide: false
});
```

Comment: i have to perform some event on the tooltip data, like i should able to click on the data and perform some event which is shown on the tooltip. You can see that functionality in http://jsfiddle.net/0w9yo8x6/4/ . The code you suggested works only if tooltip is for view purpose without performing any event within the data displayed inside tooltip. @lloiser.

Comment: try to change the position of your tooltip so it opens on the right side of the image (like http://jsfiddle.net/0w9yo8x6/5/)
see http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-position